# Burning .iso with Windows

Tags: windows, 14.04, dvd, burning

i've got a problem with burning .iso file with Windows 8.1 on Ubuntu. I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 and unfortunately corrupted Win 8 bootloader, it goes back to GRUB when i try to fire it up, or reboots a system, when i try to load it directly (set up BIOS to start Windows 8). So I downloaded new Windows 8.1 copy (the official, clean version from Dreamspark) but i've got 0xo00000e9 error when i try to run it. I burnt it twice, once with Brasero, and once with k3b so I guess i'm doing something wrong. Did anyone successfully burnt Windows DVD on Ubuntu, and have some advice about that?

Comment: Both Brasero and k3b work great..I have burnt many windows dvds looks like you are doing something wrong

Comment: But what? I've just chose .iso and burn it...

Comment: First of all I have never seen any ubuntu application giving error like `Error 0xo00000e9 has appeared`. Can you please provide screenshots?

Comment: It's when i try to boot the DVD no in application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U don't rellly need to reinstall windows 8 again.

If a system has become unbootable due to a GRUB 2 failure or corrupted MBR/boot sector, there are various methods for reinstalling GRUB 2. The simplest is via Boot-Repair Graphical Tool

Boot-Repair is a GUI application which can fix a variety of GRUB 2 problems. It can be used either from a LiveCD, its own CD, or during a normal Ubuntu session. In addition to providing a simple user interface, Boot-Repair also includes the ability to run a script to gather details of the system which can be used for troubleshooting help on various forums and IRC channels.

Please refer to the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) community documentation for instructions on how to install and run this application.

By the way, burning .iso in windows is very easy with [power2go](http://www.cyberlink.com/stat/product/free-zone/enu/free-software-static.jsp#position_b)

Comment: Yup, but I've didn't turn off fast boot option in Windows and i don't want to lose any file from NTFS partition. When i'll repair Windows boot, will it boot normally, not in the fast boot way?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)

Comment: I've repaired Windows boot, by the software you've send, fortunately the files are still where they should be. ;) Everything works now. Thanks for help :)